# how can my ESP32 be programmed with a .bin file on its SPIFFS

Tags: esp32, arduino-c++, arduino-esp32, ota, spiffs

I have an idea to download the `.bin` file from a server and save in the SPIFFS and upload the file on my ESP32. 
My problem has two parts as I am not much experienced in working with ESP32. First, how to store the `.bin` file I've downloaded in the SPIFFS and second, how to get the ESP32 programmed with the `.bin` downloaded file with no user interference and all automatically by code. 
The second part is more challenging that I couldn't find any solution for it.

I looked for a solution specially for the second part I stated, but found no solution.

Comment: maybe just use the HTTPUpdate library

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this code snippet, i hope this will help you in resolving the issue:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <SPIFFS.h>
#include <Update.h>

const char* ssid = "YourWiFiSSID";
const char* password = "YourWiFiPassword";
const char* binUrl = "http://example.com/path/to/your/file.bin"; // URL of the .bin file

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  // Connect to Wi-Fi
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");
  
  // Initialize SPIFFS
  if (!SPIFFS.begin(true)) {
    Serial.println("SPIFFS Mount Failed");
    return;
  }
  
  // Check for and perform firmware update
  checkAndPerformFirmwareUpdate();
  
  // Your setup code here
}

void loop() {
  // Your main loop code here
}

void checkAndPerformFirmwareUpdate() {
  HTTPClient http;
  http.begin(binUrl);

  int httpCode = http.GET();
  if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
    Serial.println("Downloading .bin file...");
    File firmwareFile = SPIFFS.open("/firmware.bin", FILE_WRITE);
    if (firmwareFile) {
      size_t contentLength = http.getSize();
      http.writeToStream(&firmwareFile);
      firmwareFile.close();
      Serial.println("Download complete.");

      // Perform firmware update
      if (Update.begin(contentLength)) {
        if (Update.writeStream(http.getStream())) {
          if (Update.end(true)) {
            Serial.println("Firmware update successful. Rebooting...");
            ESP.restart();
          } else {
            Serial.println("Firmware update failed!");
          }
        } else {
          Serial.println("Write to firmware update stream failed!");
        }
      } else {
        Serial.println("Begin firmware update failed!");
      }
    } else {
      Serial.println("Unable to create firmware file!");
    }
  } else {
    Serial.println("HTTP GET failed!");
  }
  http.end();
}
```